# What does the "⊢" symbol mean in ⊢ p ⇔ (p & p)?

Tags: modal-logic

⊢ p ⇔ (p & p)

what means the right part of these Entailments?

Comment: Which symbol..?

Comment: | – p  This is before p

Comment: I edited the question to replace "| -" with "⊢". It means that the formula to the right of the "⊢" symbol is provable from the formulas (assumptions) to the left of the "⊢" symbol. For example, P, P → Q ⊢ Q. When there is nothing to the left of the "⊢" symbol, it means that the formula to the right is a theorem; it's provable from *no* assumptions.

Comment: How much searching did you do? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)

Comment: @puppetsock To be fair, if you don't know it's called the turnstile and can't generate it from Unicode input, it might be difficult to go about searching for it.

Comment: @MHghasemi To be fair, even if you didn't know what it was called, you could have searched for logical symbols. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Comment: It's also worth noting the wonderful site [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)! *(Which doesn't actually help here since this site doesn't support MathJax - and probably never will, per the meta discussion [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/latex-webtex-availability) - I just like to mention it because it's cool and may be separately useful to the OP and others.)*

Comment: It means that the formula is provable in propositional calculus.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hey that's really cool! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

In general, when A is a set of sentences and x is a single sentence we write "A ⊢ x" for "A proves x." Here a fixed deduction system is implicit; generally however any reasonable choice will work (apply the relevant completeness theorem).

There are a couple abbreviations which crop up in this context which it's worth mentioning:

- When A={y_1,...,y_n} is a finite set, we often just write "y_1,...,y_n ⊢ x" for "A ⊢ x."
- In particular, when A={} we often just write "⊢ x." That's the case in your example.
- We also write "A ⊢ B" for "For all x in B, we have A ⊢ x." That's not an abbreviation which is relevant here, but it's worth mentioning.

---

So in your case, what's being said is: "The sentence 'p ⇔ (p & p)' is provable" (note that we just say "provable," not "provable without any extra premises"). You'll often hear this further abbreviated as "p ⇔ (p & p) is a tautology."

Answer (score 2):

it means that "**p ⇔ (p & p)** " can be conculded without any assumptions.
**⊢**  sign use to seperate the conclusion from its pemises/evidences/assumptions.
The Argument :
**A ⊢ B** means **B** can be concluded by **A** .
and Argument :
**⊢ C** means **C** can be concluded without any assumptions(same in your case).